# Hadoop as a substitue for ETL tools like SSIS, Informatica?

Tags: hadoop, ssis, etl, data-warehouse, informatica

I have good exposure to SSIS, Informatica for doing ETL processes & loading data into data warehouse.

But I dont have enough exposure to Hadoop.

I just wanted to know,

**Can we use Hadoop as a substitue for ETL tools like Informatica for ETL processes ?**

---

Here, basically I am talking about relational table structures. 
I know hadoop can be used to extract information from unstructured data.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be answered as asked.

The power of Hadoop comes from the synergy or MR and HDFS, moving the compute close to the data. when you're talking about using Hadoop for ETL from OLTP relational tables to a DW then Hadoop will have to connect, extract data, and do the upload. Having a cluster of workers pounding the OLTP database to extract data will help little your ETL process. Even when your T phase is complex, is seldom the case that is even a blimp on the radar compared with the E of extracting from relational DB.

The more complex, IO intensive and *not* relational tables dependent your transformation is, the better the case for Hadoop.

Hadoop would be an obvious choice if the data would be already in HDFS. With the data located in a central RDBMS, you'll need to prove the case why Hadoop would/could help.

Comment: "With the data located in a central RDBMS, you'll need to prove the case why Hadoop would/could help" - well said!

Answer (score 0):

You can do validation, transformation and profiling which are the key ETL functions, with Hadoop Map Reduce. Here are some open source solutions. They take CSV as input and generate CSV as output.

https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2015/07/28/validating-big-data/

https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/transforming-big-data/

https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/profiling-big-data/

After ETL you could use Hive for data warehousing and analytics. Another option is to use Impala.

Answer (score -1):

> **Can we use Hadoop as a substitue for ETL tools like Informatica for ETL processes ?**
>
> **Yes**,
> Why don't we think of having **ELT** like many others said ([here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402274/etl-big-data-with-hadoop.pdf)).
>
> Approach in which data is  extracted from the sources, loaded into the
> target database, and then  transformed and integrated into the desired
> format. All the heavy data  processing takes place inside the target
> database. Hadoop is right choice here to have as target database, Good
> in processing heavy data as long as we are having good reader
> for each different file format.

Comment: He wants to do ETL where Hadoop will NOT be the target storage.